# void add does not fill the array

Tags: java

I'm trying to fill the array with void fucntion but it just prints

**[]**

```
public class main
{
    double[] array = new double[1];

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        main a=new main();
         a.Add(3.5);
       
        System.out.println(a);
    }
     public void Add(double x)
    {
        var fakeArray=java.util.Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length+1);

        array[array.length-1]=x;
    }

     public int size()
    {
        return array.length;
    }

     public String toString()
     {
         String values=new String();
         values+="[";
         for (int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
             values+=String.valueOf(array[i])+",";
         }
         values+="]";
         return values;
     }

     public double average()
     {
         double total=0;
         for (int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
             total+=array[i];
         }
         return (total/array.length);
     }

}
```

void add does not fill the array with the value that I want with `a.Add(3.5);`
what Should I do the fill it, it just prints an empty array

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)` would loop over the entire array. You're looping to `array.length - 1`, which means you're skipping the final entry. Given that you only have one entry, yes, empty array prints. Note that your `fakeArray` stuff in `Add` doesn't do anything. You make a new array, assign it to a local var, and then do nothing with it.

Comment: It's a good time to learn to use the debugger in your IDE. If you don't use an IDE, you can put print statement in your code. Learning to trace your own code is an extremely important skill that you need often as a developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try mentally running through what your `toString()` method is doing. In your `for` loop, you have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
```

and we know that `array.length == 1`, since it was initialized with `new double[1]`.

So your for loop condition is `i < array.length - 1` which is `i < 1 - 1` or `i < 0`. Since this is a strict inequality and `i` is being incremented from `0`, the condition is never true.

What you need is either

```
for (int i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
```

in my opinion the second one is cleaner and more clear. It is also something you would see more commonly.